# Phone call using a number in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How can I make a phone call in my app to a number that's been input to a `UITextField`?

Comment: What event must launch phone call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to call [`openURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl) or [`openURL:options:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-openurl) with a "tel:" protocol.   See the [Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) section of the protocol reference.  In iOS 3.x you will see a prompt though in iOS 2.x it will just dial.

Comment: ok. should i have to code an line like this (with initWithString: an then phonenumber)?

    NSString *telefonnummer = map.kordinate.telefon;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telefonnummer]];

 

or another thing?
does it automatically dial when i click on the textfield?
i hope you can help me again?^^

Comment: If I understand your questions correctly, yes, yes, and maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *callTextFiel = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", textField.text];

[[UIApplication SharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:callTextField]];
```